# How does angular momentum addition work in QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, angular-momentum

So lets say we have two scalar particles, individually the particles have spin 0.  However we can make a state where between them they have orbital angular momentum.  Let's say they have total angular momentum $J=1$, does this mean the combined state transforms as a lorentz vector?

How would this generalise, for example what if we had two electrons orbiting each other?